# i am getting badly confuse in moment.js i need to compare stored date and time in database with current time which is stored in the following format

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

i have a course database which includes starting and ending date and time i have to compare the end date and time with current (system) date and time to know weather the course is expired or not if the **current time is lapsed with end time**

the stored format is like this
**"endDate": 03-09-22
"endTime": 5:00 PM**
can i compare date like this

```
let cTime=moment().format('hh:mm A');
let cDate=moment().format('DD-MM-YY');
if(endDate>cDate)
{
   console.log('yes')
}
else
console.log('no');
```

i am getting no in the output

Answer (score 0):

convert endDate to moment date
like

```
endDate = moment(endDate).format('DD-MM-YY');
```

then compare

```
if(endDate>cDate)
{
   console.log('yes')
}
```

Comment: its working i ve done this now i stucked in time comparison

Comment: how can i compare time in same way time is set to 6:30pm but getting output 1:00am